# Pydev debugger stopped working in PyCharm after Python upgrade

Tags: pycharm, pydev

I use PyCharm. I had previously built the pydev debugger under Python 3.3 using 
`python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/setup_cython.py build_ext --inplace`. 
I then had to update my project to use a new virtual environment under Python 3.5, and now the debugger won't run, with the following message:

```
/<venv_path>/bin/python3.5 /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --save-signatures --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 58286 --file /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/pytestrunner.py -p pytest_teamcity <pytest_root> <options>
Testing started at 10:25 AM ...
pydev debugger: process 94521 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 163.8233.8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1596, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 956, in run
    time.sleep(0.1)  # busy wait until we receive run command
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I tried rerunning `setup_cython.py build_ext --inplace` under the updated Python version, invalidating my caches, restarting, deleting my `.idea` folder, but nothing manages to resolve the message above.

Comment: I was able to reclaim use of the debugger by creating a project off of a newly cloned repository, which implies that there's some other cached object that all of the aforementioned steps I took together are not sufficient to truly clear a PyCharm project of its references outside of the source files. I am still curious to know if someone else has ever solved this problem.

Answer (score 10):

I resolved this issue by clearing all saved breakpoints.

Setting the environment variable PYCHARM_DEBUG=True in the launch lead me to this resolution.

Comment: I since remade the project and deleted the old one, but thank you for posting this for posterity. I did notice since that there are some stale reference bugs around breakpoints in PyCharm, the likes of which I haven't seen in Intellij.

Comment: I solve the same problem by adding: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- ` in second line