# Pycharm pydev debugger: process is connecting forever

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, pycharm, pydev

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 55819 --file "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py" --target test_output.TestMispOutputBot.test_event
Testing started at 10:31 ...
pydev debugger: process 3170 is connecting
```

**No output for 10 minutes before I give up and kill the process.**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1599, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 994, in run
    time.sleep(0.1)  # busy wait until we receive run command
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I tried everything I found regarding that error message:

- Cleared all breakpoints ([recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41353672/940592) and [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205967904-pydev-debugger-is-not-connecting))
- Deleted the .idea folder ([recommended here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205418230-Unable-to-connect-with-the-debugger) and [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205967904-pydev-debugger-is-not-connecting))
- Disabled the options *add content roots and add source roots to PYTHONPATH* ([recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45230176/940592))

Any ideas?

Comment: Try invalidate & restart

Comment: Did not change anything.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I was running `sshuttle` in the background for an SSH tunnel into another network. This tunnel was _eating_ the debug connections which should normally go to the python process.

Answer (score 2):

Solved the issue by updating `pyqt`. If you use anaconda, please try:

```
conda install -c anaconda pyqt
```